# Trying to dotnet lambda package all .csproj files in buildspec.yml

Tags: shell, aws-lambda, aws-codebuild

I got a Powershell script working locally, but the Amazon codepipeline does not allow my buildspec.yml to run PowerShell scripts. So I need a shell one-liner to do exactly the same, but alas no success yet.

Any ideas?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ./dotnet -recurse -Exclude *.Tests.csproj -Include *.csproj |  
foreach { 
cd $_.DirectoryName; 
dotnet lambda package; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

already found the answer,
since it does not support powershell on the linux images use the find command instead

```
      find ./dotnet/  -name "*.csproj" ! -name "*.Tests.csproj"  -execdir dotnet lambda package {} \;
```